# Django success url using kwargs

Tags: python, django

I am trying to amend my `get_success_url` so that if any `kwargs` have been passed to it, I can build the returned url using them.

Heres what I have so far:

```
class CalcUpdate(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Calc
    template_name = 'calc/cru_template.html'
    form_class = CalcForm

    def archive_calc(self, object_id):
        model_a = Calc.objects.get(id = object_id)
        model_b = Calc()

        for field in model_a._meta.fields:
            setattr(model_b, field.name, getattr(model_a, field.name))
        model_b.pk = None
        model_b.save()

        self.get_success_url(idnumber = model_b.pk)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #objects
        if self.object.checked == True:
            object_id = self.object.id
            self.archive_calc(object_id)
        #save

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
        if  kwargs != None:
            return reverse_lazy('detail', kwargs = {'pk': kwargs['idnumber']})
        else:
            return reverse_lazy('detail', args = (self.object.id,))
```

So far this just gives a `keyerror` detailing `'idnumber'`.

I have printed `kwargs['idnumber']` and it returns the `pk` as expected however I just cant seem to see where I am going wrong with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `get_success_url` doesn't get called with keywords arguments within Django's generic views.

Comment: @simeon So I cant pass anything to it at all? The end result is just to be able to redirect to a newly created pk if it has been created by the view.

Comment: Where are you getting `idnumber` from? You must get it somehow when you pass it to `get_success_url` so how does the view know about it?

Comment: @ngenator It gets it when it is passed from else where in the view using self.get_success_url(idnumber = model_b.pk)

Comment: Can you add the rest of that view code?

Comment: Try replacing `if  kwargs != None:` with `if 'idnumber' in kwargs:`

Comment: @ngenator I have just amended my question with a more detailed example of my UpdateView. Ill try the above now. If it makes any difference I know the if statement is working as it only fails/errors when I pass it something.

Comment: @ngenator I just ran you answer and it skipped (went to 'else') as if 'idnumber' was not present in kwargs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64823/discussion-between-karl-and-ngenator).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`form_valid` should return a `HttpResponseRedirect` https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L57 which in your case, you never do. I dont know if you have any code after `#save`, but take a look at the comments I made in your code

```
class CalcUpdate(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Calc
    template_name = 'calc/cru_template.html'
    form_class = CalcForm

    def archive_calc(self, object_id):
        model_a = Calc.objects.get(id = object_id)
        model_b = Calc()

        for field in model_a._meta.fields:
            setattr(model_b, field.name, getattr(model_a, field.name))
        model_b.pk = None
        model_b.save()

        return self.get_success_url(idnumber = model_b.pk) # you never return this value

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #objects
        if self.object.checked == True:
            object_id = self.object.id
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.archive_calc(object_id)) # you never return a `HttpResponse`
        #save  -- If this is where you are saving... you can store the value from archive and return it after saving

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
        if  kwargs != None:
            return reverse_lazy('detail', kwargs = {'pk': kwargs['idnumber']})
        else:
            return reverse_lazy('detail', args = (self.object.id,))
```

Also you don't need to manually copy the fields, just do (assuming there are no `unique` constraints because if there were, your version would fail too):

```
    def archive_calc(self, object_id):
        c = self.model.objects.get(id = object_id)
        c.pk = None
        c.save()

        return self.get_success_url(idnumber = c.pk)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Still gives the same error regarding 'idnumber' im afraid. Been trying other solutions this morning but still no joy.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with @Ngenator's answer and various other posts on here I have the following working code. However its not very nice to look at :(

```
def get_success_url(self):
    if self.pknumber != None:
        return reverse_lazy('pstdetail', args = (self.pknumber,))
    else:
        return reverse_lazy('pstdetail', args = (self.object.id,))
```

I have this `self.pknumber = model_b.pk` in the necessary place within the view and `self.pknumber = None` else where to enable the if statement to build the required url. Hope this helps anyone and feel free to point out any errors/improvements.

Comment: Sorry, i was about to answer and suggest you do something similar, or change from `**kwargs` to an actual keyword argument.

Comment: Also, you should really use `if self.pknumber is not None`

Answer (score 1):

https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/

You cannot pass parameters in `get_success_url(self)` method. You can only refer to `self` parameter. For example `self.kwargs['pk']`.