# Redirect to next URL in django FormView

Tags: django, redirect, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am using `Django 1.7` with `Python 3.4`. I have a scenario where I wish the users to be redirected to another view, as defined in the `next` GET parameter, after they login. But with my current setup, they always get redirected to the home page. I was hoping there is a way to do this in the `get_success_url` of the `FormView` class.

Below is my code

The next parameter in the URL

```
http://localhost:8000/login/?next=/ads/new
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView 

class LoginView(FormView):

    template_name = 'users/login.html'
    form_class = LoginForm

    def get_success_url(self):                           
        return reverse('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
        login(self.request, form.user)
        messages.info(self.request, 'Login successful')
        return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
url(r'^new$', 'apps.adverts.views.add_new_advert', name='new_advert'), # URL to use after login, in next param
```

With the above setup, how do I redirect to the next URL if it is defined, apart from the home page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django success url using kwargs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897050/django-success-url-using-kwargs)

Comment: I've looked at the link mentioned above, and while it deals with redirecting to another object/view, it does not show how to get the `GET` parameters in the `get_success_url` method inorder to pass in the `next` URL.

Answer (score 12):

Include the data as GET parameters in your success url.

```
def get_success_url(self):
   # find your next url here
   next_url = self.request.POST.get('next',None) # here method should be GET or POST.
   if next_url:
       return "%s" % (next_url) # you can include some query strings as well
   else :
       return reverse('home') # what url you wish to return
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: did you seen you getting next in self.request.POST. As this is working for me. you should check is your next param coming on POST or GET.

Comment: Try self.request.GET('next', None).