# Django - dynamic success_url in UpdateView

Tags: django

I want my user to be able to see a page, update that page, and then be returned to that page or continue making more edits.

Here's the view to show the information:

```
    # urls.py      
url(r'^gameview/$', views.GameView.as_view(template_name='matchview.html'), name='GameView')

# Views.py
class GameView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "matchview.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(GameView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        q = self.request.GET.get('match')
        context['report'] = GameNotes.objects.filter(game=q)
        context['game'] = Schedule.objects.get(match=q)
        context['gamepic'] = Photo.objects.filter(game=q)
        return context
```

So now they want to add information about a game. I use an UpdateView

```
class GameView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "matchview.html"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(GameView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    q = self.request.GET.get('match')
    context['report'] = GameNotes.objects.filter(game=q)
    context['game'] = Schedule.objects.get(match=q)
    context['gamepic'] = Photo.objects.filter(game=q)
    return context
```

When the user finishes updating in the latter view, they should be returned to the former on the exact same team. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897050/django-success-url-using-kwargs) helped me move in the right direction insofar as using 'get_success_url', but I'm still stuck because I don't think I'm using kwargs. Everything I've tried has resulted in errors.

(My (gulp) thought is that I should re-write the urls to use PKs so that this stuff is easier, but I wanted to make sure)

EDIT:
My fugly attempt (Note: I  Have two submit buttons, one to update and one to update and add notes).

```
     def form_valid(self, form):
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    if 'submit' in self.request.POST:
        q = self.request.GET.get('match')
        return reverse_lazy('TeamView', args=(q))
    else:
        return render('addnotes', {'game' : q})
```

SOLUTION:

Learned how to use URL Parameters and kwargs:
(for anyone new like me, self.kwargs.get is brilliant)

```
def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        q = self.kwargs.get('match')
        if "submit" in self.request.POST:
        url = reverse('GameView', args={q : 'match'})
        else:
            url = reverse('AddNotes', args={q : 'match'})
        return url
```

Comment: You don't need to use PKs, but you really should use URL parameters rather than querystrings.

Comment: Please show what you've tried with `get_success_url`. Having the primary key in the url (`/gameview/1/)` is cleaner than in the querystring (`/gameview/?match=1`), but you don't have to switch if you don't want to. You can access `self.request.GET.get('match')` in your `get_success_url`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman can I ask why? more secure?

Comment: @Alasdair I figured using `def form_valid` was the way to go. I updated

Comment: You don't need to check `form.is_valid()` in the `form_valid` method - the method will only be called when the form is valid. In the `form_valid`, you must return a response - returning the string from `reverse_lazy` will not work. Finally, it might be better to redirect to the `addnotes` view instead of rendering the template. In that case it would be better to override `get_success_url` instead of `form_valid`.

Comment: @Alasdair got it. What's the format to send the user to a my link? (using a querystring for now)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. In the `form_valid` you must return a response, so use `redirect` or `HttpResponseRedirect`. But as I said before, I think you should be overriding `get_success_url` and returning a string.

Answer (score 6):

What about get_absolute_url for the model object?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

```
from django.urls import reverse

class GameModel(models.Model):
    ....

    def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('game:single_page', args=[str(self.id)])
```

And in your GameView:

```
class GameView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "matchview.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ....

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return self.object.get_absolute_url()
```

Comment: That...could...work? Thank you, I'll update when I have a chance!