# Django CreateForm - redirect to same form on success

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a page that contains a blog post, with a comment form above the list of comments, to allow users to add a comment.
The blog post has the following url (where `blog_id` is a url parameter):

```
/blog/<blog_id>
```

Url pattern:

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('post/<blog_id>', BlogPostView.as_view(), name="BlogPostView"),
]
```

The view function:

```
class BlogPostView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'blog_post.html'
    form_class = BlogCommentCreationForm
    success_url = ???

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['blog_post'] = CompanyBlogPost.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['blog_id'])
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.publish_datetime = dt.now()
        form.instance.blogpost = CompanyBlogPost.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['blog_id'])
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Firstly, is this a reasonable way of implementing this?

Secondly, everything here works, aside from the `success_url`. The submission of the form should create the comment, and redirect to the same page. How should I define `success_url`?
I would like to use:

```
success_url = reverse_lazy(BlogPostView, kwargs={'blog_id': self.kwargs['blog_id']})
```

However, this fails, as BlogPostView is used within its own definition.

Comment: What is your complete url pattern? Also have in mind from the docs `# passing a callable object
# (This is discouraged because you can't reverse namespaced views this way.)`

Comment: @guillermochamorro I've updated the question. Is this a bad approach, or is there some way around it?

Comment: Didn't you try to use the name: `reverse_lazy("BlogPostView",...`?

Comment: @guillermochamorro With no arguments it won't resolve. The view requires a blog_id parameter to know which blog to display

Comment: Yes, I just was lazy :P to put the full statement. But the important part is to try the view _name_, not the view itself.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Ah ok, sorry. That looks promising,  but now it can't find self.kwargs... - self is not defined at this point

Comment: Use the `get_success_url` method instead of `success_url`, you can find an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26899495/6005145

Comment: That solved it, thank you. If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the url `name` instead of the view, which acording to the docs is discouraged:

> you can use any of the following to reverse the URL:
>
> using the named URL
>
> `reverse('news-archive')`
>
> passing a callable object *(This is discouraged because you can't
>   reverse namespaced views this way.)*
>
> `from news import views`
>
> `reverse(views.archive)`

and use the `get_success_url` method to pass the `kwargs` instead of `success_url`:

```
class BlogPostView(CreateView):
    # ...

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy('BlogPostView', kwargs={'blog_id': self.kwargs['blog_id'])
                             # ^ url name
```